# How does Azureus get my firewall to open a port (Debian Linux)?

Tags: linux, firewall, port-forwarding

I downloaded Azureus (a bittorrent client) for Debian Linux, and I notice that Azureus got my firewall (a Verizon wireless base station) to open a TCP and UDP port forwarding for it, without my having to do anything.  My base station is password protected, and I'm alarmed at the idea that any random application can open ports without my knowing about it.

Can somebody explain to me what is going on and how it is possible that Azureus can create this port-forwarding rule without any authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play#NAT_traversal) or [NAT-PMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_Port_Mapping_Protocol).